# Perform a SVN merge in TeamCity (or MSBuild)

Tags: svn, msbuild, teamcity

I need to merge an SVN branch into the trunk during a TeamCity (6.5) build. it currently checks out the trunk and then starts to compile/test/deploy etc the project.

Just before the compile stage, I want to merge a branch into it.

I had a quick look at the MSBuild community tasks and although there are some SVN tasks available, I couldn't see a 'merge' one.

Are there some MSBuild tasks I can use to do this, or can TeamCity do this for me out of the box?

**EDIT**: nearly got it working using:

```
<Exec Command="svn merge $(BranchToMerge) C:\BuildAgentB\work\CheckoutDirectory\MyProject" Condition="'$(BranchToMerge)'!=''" />
```

However it keeps telling me *C:\BuildAgentB\work\CheckoutDirectory\MyProject* is not a working copy. It should be though. I have made sure that both TeamCity VCS Settings and the svn.exe are using subversion 1.6 so they should be using the correct working copy format (1.6 is the highest my version of TC supports). But there's no .svn folder in the checkout directory. Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Is TeamCity performing an export or a checkout of your code? How will you handle conflicts that result from your merge?

Comment: Yep that's a valid point. I was hoping to get a 'no conflict' scenario working first and then think about that later. The most obvious solution (to me) for when a conflict arises would be to simply fail the build though.

Comment: Ah you are right I think it exports by default

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/VCS+Checkout+Mode

Comment: So, setting it to 'Automatically on Build Agent' rather than 'on Server' does a checkout rather than an export. I then found out that the build was hanging for 10 minutes until I realised it was waiting for a username and password but that's easily rectified with svn merge --username xxxxxxxx --password yyyyyyy